# MS Word VBA in document saved in word 2003 causes error in 2010 64 bit

Tags: vba, ms-word, 64-bit

I have a document that has VBA macros in it and when I try to open it in word 2010 64bit
it complains that the code should be updated for use on 64 bit systems. 
I added conditional compilation clauses #If Not 64Bit but this did not help. 
Is there anything else that might be done?

Answer (score 1):

Are you using any ActiveX controls? For example, if your Word application displays a custom UserForm then it is likely that the controls on it (including some of the built-in ones) won't work properly.

From [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee691831%28office.14%29.aspx):

> ActiveX Control and COM Add-in
>   Compatibility
>
> Existing 32-bit ActiveX controls, both
>   third-party and Microsoft-supplied,
>   are not compatible with the 64-bit
>   version of Office 2010. For ActiveX
>   controls and COM objects, there are
>   three possible solutions:
>
> - If you have the source code, you can generate a 64-bit version yourself,
> - You can contact the vendor for an updated version,
> - You can search for an alternative solution.
>
> Native 64-bit processes in Office 2010
>   cannot load 32-bit binaries. This
>   includes the common controls of
>   MSComCtl (TabStrip, Toolbar,
>   StatusBar, ProgressBar, TreeView,
>   ListViews, ImageList, Slider,
>   ImageComboBox) and the controls of
>   MSComCt2 (Animation, UpDown,
>   MonthView, DateTimePicker,
>   FlatScrollBar).These controls were
>   installed by previous versions of
>   Microsoft Office and are installed by
>   32-bit Office 2010. An alternative
>   must be found for existing Microsoft
>   Office VBA solutions that utilize
>   these controls when the code is
>   migrated to 64-bit Office 2010. 64-bit
>   Office 2010 does not provide 64-bit
>   versions of the Common Controls.

---

`Declare` statments are also affected when using the 64-bit version of Office:

> In previous versions of VBA, there was
>   no specific pointer data type so the
>   Long data type was used. And because
>   the Long data type is always 32-bits,
>   this breaks when used on a system with
>   64-bit memory because the upper
>   32-bits may be truncated or may
>   overwrite other memory addresses.
>   Either of these situations can result
>   in unpredictable behavior or system
>   crashes.

Example of old `Declare` statement:

`Declare Function RegOpenKeyA Lib "advapi32.dll" (ByVal Key As Long, ByVal SubKey As String, NewKey As Long) As Long`

> To resolve this, VBA now contains a
>   true pointer data type: LongPtr.

New version:

`Declare PtrSafe Function RegOpenKeyA Lib "advapi32.dll" (ByVal Key As LongPtr, ByVal SubKey As String, NewKey As LongPtr) As Long`

> This data type and the new PtrSafe
>   attribute enable you to use this
>   Declare statement on either 32-bit or
>   64-bit systems. The PtrSafe attribute
>   indicates to the VBA compiler that the
>   Declare statement is targeted for the
>   64-bit version of Office 2010. Without
>   this attribute, using the Declare
>   statement in a 64-bit system will
>   result in a compile-time error. Note
>   that the PtrSafe attribute is optional
>   on the 32-bit version of Office 2010.
>   This enables existing Declare
>   statements to work as they always
>   have.

Quotes taken from [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee691831%28office.14%29.aspx) again

Comment: Thank you. It complains about declare statements in VBA so I do not think ActiveX controls are to blame

Comment: @SparcU - `Declare` statements are affected too - I'll update my answer